# emacs search and replace

Tags: emacs

seen lot of links but not able to figure out , what is

```
M-% query replace
```

what key board button i need to press for putting query to replace.

Not finding exactly what keyboard button.

Pls tell how can i do search and replace in emacs

http://lpn.rnbhq.org/tools/xemacs/emacs_ref.html

http://kb.iu.edu/data/abdp.html

Comment: Note that `M` stands for "Meta", which was the name of a modifier key on older keyboards (along with "Super" and "Hyper" which can also crop up in Emacs discussion, but are not used in any default bindings; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-cadet_keyboard ). Virtually no keyboards have a Meta key these days, which is why Alt is used.

Comment: I'm sorry, what?. The **first** hit you get for "query-replace emacs" (A fairly complex issue with multiple aspects) on Stack Overflow is this? ;(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

M In emacs is the "Alt Key"

% Is itself so = [Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_key) + 5

To make a query replace to must press at the same time:

```
Alt + Shift + 5
```

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with emacs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "M-x replace-string", It means that you need press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, then input "replace-string" then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now, you can type in what to search. After an other <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you can type in what it should be replaced.
Or you can set a hotkey in your dotemacs file. like:

```lisp
(global-set-key [f11] 'replace-string)
```

then, you can use <kbd>F11</kbd> to call this function.

Comment: -1 This is the correct answer to a different, albeit related, question.

Comment: No, it's the correct answer to the only humanly-understandable question that can be (quite painfully I must say) extracted from.. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716440/emacs-search-and-replace). And you down-voted it.

BTW what is, in your light, the 'correct answer'? (Please tell me question as well)

Answer (score 1):

M is for `meta` in olden days (I never seen that key myself). its <kbd>alt</kbd> key for me. you can also press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get `meta` key.

So two ways to get `M-%`.

`Alt + Shift + 5` (press all at a time)

or

press <kbd>Esc</kbd> later `Shift + 5` (i.e., `%`)